# How to disable "AllowPrinting" for PDF generated in cfreport/cfdocument?

Tags: coldfusion, cfdocument, cfreport

The business requirement says that the PDF cannot be printed.

I looked up the [doc of cfreport](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c1d.html), and it says for `format="pdf"`, there is a `permissions` attribute that I can set to a list of permissions including `AllowPrinting`.

However, setting `permissions=""` does not take away the printing permission.  I checked by Right Cick on Adobe Reader browser plugin -> Document Property -> Security, it says Printing: Allowed"

How do I disable printing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out in the doc of `CFPDF` that `encryption` attribute must be set before it respects `permissions` attribute!